# WSO2 EI Realtime Datamapper Priview Not working?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I tried WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Data-mapper mediator to convert JSON to XML. But when I try to click Try out button in the Realtime datamapper priview, it is not working. Can anyone help me to solve this issue, I am new to WSO2 EI?

I tried like below example
[Creating a SOAP payload with namespaces](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/data-Mapper-Mediator/#example-1-creating-a-soap-payload-with-namespaces)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhv4F.png)
This is my WSO2 EI screenshot.

Comment: Which Integration Studio version are you using?

Comment: I used WSO2 EI 6.6.0 version